# Filter arrays inside array

Tags: javascript

I have an array that contains arrays and objects, and I want a function to filter only the arrays inside the initial array, example:

```
const myArray = [
  [1,2,4],
  {name:'john'},
  [2,4,5],
  {name: 'jack'}
]
```

And then get a variable that only contains [1,2,4] and [2,4,5]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter` to return values based on a condition. Below uses the `.isArray` method of `Array` class to determine if a value is an array.

```
const arrays = myArray.filter(Array.isArray)
```

Example:

```js
const myArray = [
  [1,2,4],
  {name:'john'},
  [2,4,5],
  {name: 'jack'}
]

const arrays = myArray.filter(Array.isArray)

console.log(arrays)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
const myArray = [
 [1,2,4],
 {name:'john'},
 [2,4,5],
{name: 'jack'}
]
let arr= myArray.filter((elem)=>{
                   return Array.isArray(elem);
              })
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.filter` returns a new array. It executes a callback for every item in the array. The first argument of the first callback is the first item, the first argument of the second callback is the second item etc. If the callback returns a truthy value, the item that was the first argument of that callback is added to the new array.

`Array.isArray(arg)` returns a boolean based on if the argument is an Array.

```js
const myArray = [
    [1,2,4],
    {name:'john'},
    [2,4,5],
    {name: 'jack'}
]

function untitled(array) {
    return array.filter((item) => Array.isArray(item));
}   

answer = untitled(myArray);
console.log(answer);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
myArray.filter(v=>Array.isArray(v))
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.